# Idioms for checking that an InputStream has been closed?

Tags: java, file-io, inputstream, ioexception

I'm using a PipedInputStream to send data between things. When the PipedOutputStream that connects to the PipedInputStream is closed, there appears to be no way to detect that the PipedInputStream is no longer able to read data. For now, I'm using `try { ... } catch(IOException e) { ... }`.

Is there a more idiomatic way to detect a closed input stream, or is that all Java offers? I looked at the API docs, expecting a `boolean isOpen()` or such, but could not find one.

Answer (score 0):

You could try building an observer model style system such that when `PipedOutputStream` is closed, it sends a signal that the `PipedInputStream` picks up on via a listener. So on one side you would have `PipedOutputStream.signalClosing()`, and on the other side you have `onOutputStreamClosing(Event e)` function that handles the event (perhaps by setting a bool, or just closing the input stream out right).

Answer (score 0):

I would say open the communication channel in other direction. Then when closing `PipedOutputStream`, you can send a byte to the side using `PipedInputStream`, and you react by closing output and input streams on both side. Otherwise you are stuck with the try catch construct, there is no other 100 percent way of saying, that the stream on other side is closed, than trying to send data.

Comment: Yes, that would work. Though it's a lot of overhead for something I think Java streams should have included out of the box.

Comment: I agree with you, unfortunately it does not :(